# Why the backgroundworker never get to the completed event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the DoWork event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            distance = 0; counter = 0;
            if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                while (counter < 200)
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    distance = (float)counter;
                    DateTime dt1, dt2;
                    dt1 = DateTime.Now;
                    CloudEnteringAlert.cloudalert(localbmp, distance);
                    dt2 = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
                    Logger.Write(ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
                    if (counter == 199)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        CloudEnteringAlert.ClearList();
                        //break;

                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (completed == true)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                if (CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsfound == true)
                                {
                                    listBox1.Items.Add("Cloud detected at: " + CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text + " Kilometers from the coast");
                                    timesdetectedclouds += 1;
                                    label2.Visible = true;
                                    label2.Text = timesdetectedclouds.ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    listBox1.Items.Add("Cloud not detected at: " + CloudEnteringAlert.cloudsdistance.Text + " Kilometers from the coast");
                                    timesnotdetectedclouds += 1;
                                    label4.Visible = true;
                                    label4.Text = timesnotdetectedclouds.ToString();
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        Logger.Write(err.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And in the completed event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {

            }

            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {

            }

            else
            {
               string t = "Done!";
               completed = true;
            }
```

But it never get to the IF in the completed event.

What i want to do in general is in the DoWork event to add to the listBox1 the items only once.
But it keep doing it over and over again nonstop.
If i will use the Break; here:

```
if (counter == 199)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        CloudEnteringAlert.ClearList();
                        //break;
                    }
```

It will get to the completed event and will stop.
But i don't want to stop the backgorundworker i want only to do the part with the listBox1 only once when it's getting to 199 don't keep adding to the listBox1 again but keep to do the other things again.

Comment: ReportProgress would be really nice...and aside from that,maybe you have an infinite loop on your hands...remenber that counter and distance are from another thread so maybe a race condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the backgroundWorker1_DoWork code to keep running but you want the backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted event to fire when DoWork has processed 199 items. The "Completed" event means that the DoWork code is done processing instead of "done doing something". I think TerryBozzio has a good suggestion. Call ReportProgress to fire the ProgressChanged event the first time counter == 199.

Comment: codeMethod i want to make the listBox1.Add part once. It dosen't matter if it's getting to the completed event or not i need that it will do only the listBox1 part once. And the rest to keep on nonstop. When counter == 199 i want that it will not make the listBox1 part again but will keep do the rest nonstop over and over again. The problem is how to make the listBox1 part once. I used the report progress and it's getting to the completed event but then everything stop.

Comment: In your code where you test if (completed == true) return;... can you change to if (completed == true) continue;